# Why does checking whether a file exists in hadoop cause a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm trying to create or open a file to store some output in HDFS, but I'm getting a NullPointerException when I call the `exists` method in the second to last line of the code snippet below:

```
DistributedFileSystem dfs = new DistributedFileSystem();
Path path = new Path("/user/hadoop-user/bar.txt");
if (!dfs.exists(path)) dfs.createNewFile(path);
FSDataOutputStream dos = dfs.create(path);
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.dfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:390)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:667)
        at ClickViewSessions$ClickViewSessionsMapper.map(ClickViewSessions.java:80)
        at ClickViewSessions$ClickViewSessionsMapper.map(ClickViewSessions.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:47)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:227)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$Child.main(TaskTracker.java:2209)
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: Could you post the exception stacktrace?

Comment: I added the stack trace.

Comment: mhh nothing is documented in http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.17.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/dfs/DistributedFileSystem.html  :-/ I guess you should try to open an issue for this. Check  the mailing list: http://hadoop.apache.org/mailing_lists.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the preferred way of doing this is:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://mynamenodehost:9000");
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
Path path = ...
```

That way you don't tie your code to a particular implementation of FileSystem; plus you don't have to worry about how each implementation of FileSystem is initialized.

Comment: what do I substitute for the Strings in `conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://mynamenodehost:9000")`?

Comment: oh, ok I just substituted the result of `ifconfig` on the vm and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

The default constructor DistributedFileSystem() does not perform initialization; you need to call dfs.initialize() explicitly.

The reason you are getting a null pointer exception is that the DistributedFileSystem internally uses an instance of DFSClient. Since you did not call initialize(), the instance of DFSClient is null. getFileStatus() calls dfsClient.getFileInfo(getPathName(f) - which causes  NullPointerException, since dfsClient is null.

See https://trac.declarativity.net/browser/src/hdfs/org/apache/hadoop/dfs/DistributedFileSystem.java?rev=3593

Comment: dfs.initialize() requires two arguments, a URI and a Configuration. I assume the Configuration is just the JobConf that the client is set to. What about the URI? According to the documentation the URI is "a uri whose authority section names the host, port, etc. for this FileSystem." How do I get that?

Answer (score 1):

> This shoud work

```
DistributedFileSystem dfs = new DistributedFileSystem();
dfs.initialize(new URI("URI to HDFS"), new Configuration());
Path path = new Path("/user/hadoop-user/bar.txt");
if (!dfs.exists(path)) dfs.createNewFile(path);
FSDataOutputStream dos = dfs.create(path);
```