# apache spark - check if file exists

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I am new to spark and I have a question. I have a two step process in which the first step write a SUCCESS.txt file to a location on HDFS. My second step which is a spark job has to verify if that SUCCESS.txt file exists before it starts processing the data.

I checked the spark API and didnt find any method which checks if a file exists. Any ideas how to handle this?

The only method I found was sc.textFile(hdfs:///SUCCESS.txt).count() which would throw an exception when the file does not exist. I have to catch that exception and write my program accordingly. I didnt really like this approach. Hoping to find a better alternative.

Answer (score 58):

For a file in HDFS, you can use the [hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727901/why-does-checking-whether-a-file-exists-in-hadoop-cause-a-nullpointerexception) way of doing this:

```
val conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
val fs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(conf)
val exists = fs.exists(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("/path/on/hdfs/to/SUCCESS.txt"))
```

Answer (score 22):

For Pyspark, you can achieve this without invoking a subprocess using something like:

```
fs = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
fs.exists(sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("path/to/SUCCESS.txt"))
```

Comment: elegant solution!

Comment: finally, I find it!

Answer (score 11):

I will say, best way to call this through function which internally check for file presence in the traditional hadoop file check.

```
object OutputDirCheck {
  def dirExists(hdfsDirectory: String): Boolean = {
    val hadoopConf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration()
    val fs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(hadoopConf)
    fs.exists(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(hdfsDirectory))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Using Databricks **dbutils**:

```
def path_exists(path):
  try:
    if len(dbutils.fs.ls(path)) > 0:
      return True
  except:
    return False
```

Comment: shorter way:

`def path_exists(path):
  return len(dbutils.fs.ls(path)) > 0`

Answer (score 4):

for **Spark 2.0 or higher** you can use the method exist of hadoop.fr.FileSystem
 :

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Test extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("BigDataETL - Check if file exists")
    .getOrCreate()

  val fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
  // This methods returns Boolean (true - if file exists, false - if file doesn't exist
  val fileExists = fs.exists(new Path("<parh_to_file>"))
  if (fileExists) println("File exists!")
  else println("File doesn't exist!")
}
```

for **Spark 1.6 to 2.0**

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object Test extends App {
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(s"BigDataETL - Check if file exists")
  val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
  val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
  val fileExists = fs.exists(new Path("<parh_to_file>"))
  if (fileExists) println("File exists!")
  else println("File doesn't exist!")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For PySpark:

```
from py4j.protocol import Py4JJavaError
def path_exist(path):
    try:
        rdd = sc.textFile(path)
        rdd.take(1)
        return True
    except Py4JJavaError as e:
        return False
```

Answer (score 2):

For Java coders;

```
 SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myClassname");
        SparkContext sparky = new SparkContext(sparkConf);       
        JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(sparky);

     FileSystem hdfs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(context.hadoopConfiguration());
            Path path = new Path(sparkConf.get(path_to_File));

            if (!hdfs.exists(path)) {
                 //Path does not exist.
            } 
         else{
               //Path exist.
           }
```

Comment: For me `sparkConf.get(path_to_File)` complains the file does not exist which is the thing I was trying to avoid. `new Path(path_to_File)` directly however works.

Answer (score 2):

For pyspark python users:

i didn't find anything with python or pyspark so we need to execute hdfs command from python code. This has worked for me.

hdfs command to get if folder exisits : returning 0 if true

```
hdfs dfs -test -d /folder-path
```

hdfs command to get if file exists : returning 0 if true

```
hdfs dfs -test -d /folder-path
```

For putting this in python code i followed below lines of code :

```
import subprocess

def run_cmd(args_list):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc.communicate()
    return proc.returncode

cmd = ['hdfs', 'dfs', '-test', '-d', "/folder-path"]
            code = run_cmd(cmd)
if code == 0:
    print('folder exist')
    print(code)
```

Output if folder exists :

folder exists
0

Answer (score 0):

@Nandeesh's answer evaluates all the `Py4JJavaError` exceptions. I propose to add another step to evaluate java exception error message:

```py
from py4j.protocol import Py4JJavaError


def file_exists(path):
    try:
        spark.sparkContext.textFile(path).take(1)
    except Py4JJavaError as e:
        if 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist' in str(e.java_exception):
            return False
        else:
            return True
```