# Spark : Read file only if the path exists

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

I am trying to read the files present at `Sequence` of Paths in scala. Below is the sample (pseudo) code:

```
val paths = Seq[String] //Seq of paths
val dataframe = spark.read.parquet(paths: _*)
```

Now, in the above sequence, some paths exist whereas some don't. Is there any way to ignore the missing paths while reading `parquet` files (to avoid `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist`)?

I have tried the below and it seems to be working, but then, I end up reading the same path twice which is something I would like to avoid doing:

```
val filteredPaths = paths.filter(p => Try(spark.read.parquet(p)).isSuccess)
```

I checked the `options` method for `DataFrameReader` but that does not seem to have any option that is similar to `ignore_if_missing`.

Also, these paths can be `hdfs` or `s3` (this `Seq` is passed as a method argument) and while reading, I don't know whether a path is `s3` or `hdfs` so can't use `s3` or `hdfs` specific API to check the existence.

Answer (score 25):

You can filter out the irrelevant files as in @Psidom's answer. In spark, the best way to do so is to use the internal spark hadoop configuration. Given that spark session variable is called "spark" you can do:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

val hadoopfs: FileSystem = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)

def testDirExist(path: String): Boolean = {
  val p = new Path(path)
  hadoopfs.exists(p) && hadoopfs.getFileStatus(p).isDirectory
}
val filteredPaths = paths.filter(p => testDirExists(p))
val dataframe = spark.read.parquet(filteredPaths: _*)
```

Comment: Depending on your system setup, you may need to specify your filesystem location in the get: `FileSystem.get(new URI("s3://bucket"), spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)`. Otherwise, it might create an HDFS filesystem and barf on checking the path of an S3 filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

How about filtering the `paths` firstly`:

```
paths.filter(f => new java.io.File(f).exists)
```

For instance:

```
Seq("/tmp", "xx").filter(f => new java.io.File(f).exists)
// res18: List[String] = List(/tmp)
```

Comment: `Paths` can be local `hdfs` paths or `s3` paths. Not sure whether `File.exists` would work for `s3`.

Comment: Would require slightly different API for checking path existence if the paths are HDFS / S3 paths (which are commonly used with Spark). [@DarshanMehta you beat me to it by 3 seconds :)]

Comment: @TzachZohar haha yes. I have updated the question now.

Comment: For S3, you might want to check [doesObjectExist](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#doesObjectExist-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), and for hdfs, you could see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405728/apache-spark-check-if-file-exists).

Answer (score 2):

Since Spark 2.3.0 there is a config `spark.sql.files.ignoreMissingFiles`. Just set it to `true`.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: This only seems to work on files. If path is a non-existent directory, it will have no effect.

Comment: As of Spark 3.3.1, `spark.sql.files.ignoreMissingFiles` is meant for files that go missing after data frame construction: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.3.1/docs/sql-data-sources-generic-options.md.

Answer (score 1):

### PySpark 3.1 or greater

Sadly there isn't any flag yet in pyspark (at least I am not aware of) to ignore them as of Spark 3.1. But you can try these simple things. The good news is that the load interface works on lists too. See below.

```
# add you list of paths here
addrs = ["path1", "path2", ...]

# check if they exists, update the list
for add in addrs:
    try:
        spark.read.format("parquet").load(add)
    except:
        print(add)
        addrs.remove(add)

# read the updated list now
sdf_a = spark\
        .read\
        .format("parquet")\
        .load(addrs)
```

Comment: The fact that they have a read, write, and don't have an exists check makes me so mad i'm going to downvote this answer. sorry

Comment: This answer seems nicely "pythonic" to me -- it does not require that we know why a read failed or how to evaluate whether or not it will fail, just that it does fail. Since Spark is lazy, these loads should not be a significant burden to the runtime. I also like that I don't need to learn anything new about the HDFS or s3.

Comment: tried this and there are instances that slip through

Answer (score 0):

@s510 has a nice answer with a pythonic "duck typing" inspired style. However, I prefer to use immutability where possible, so I would rewrite it like this:

```py
def path_is_readable(x):
  try:
    spark.read.parquet(x)
    return True
  except:
    return False

valid_paths = [p for p in paths if path_is_readable(p)]
dataframe = spark.read.parquet(*valid_paths)
```