# Spark-scala : Check whether a S3 directory exists or not before reading it

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

How to check if a S3 directory exists or not before reading it?

I was trying this, as given here http://bigdatatech.taleia.software/2015/12/21/check-if-exists-a-amazon-s3-path-from-apache-spark/

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
fs.listStatus(new Path("s3://s3bucket/2017/10/31/*/*/"))
```

but getting this error
`Wrong FS: s3://s3bucket/2017/10/31/*/*, expected: hdfs://ip-172-31-55-167.ec2.internal:8020`

I can check whether the exact file exists or not using its exact path,
but I have to use wild cards like here "s3://s3bucket/2017/10/31/ */ *" which it doesn't support.

Checked this StackOverflow question: [Spark : Read file only if the path exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193825/spark-read-file-only-if-the-path-exists) , but its not related to my use-case.

Comment: use `fs.globStatus`

Comment: also try, `FileSystem.get(new java.net.URI("s3://s3bucket") )` or something along the lines of that. I also believe theres a dedicated API provided by Hadoop for dealing with S3 FS

Comment: Tried, still giving the same error
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: s3://myS3Bucket/2017/10/31, expected: hdfs://ip-172-31-55-167.ec2.internal:8020`

Answer (score 14):

This is because when you call `FileSystem.get(new Configuration())`, the file system resolved is the default file system which in this case is `hdfs`.

You first need to obtain the right file system by providing an URI from a path which contains the `s3` scheme and your bucket.

It would also be better to use the Hadoop configuration of your current Spark context, to ensure you will use the same file system settings as Spark.

```
import java.net.URI
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

// Create a session with Spark master running locally (vs on a cluster)
// for development purposes
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
                               .appName("My App")
                               .master("local")
                               .getOrCreate

val conf = sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
val fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create("s3://s3bucket/"), conf)
```

This will work only if you have an implementation of the S3 file system on your classpath. I can see you are running your program on an EC2 instance so you should be able to access S3 without specifying explicit AWS credentials.

Comment: What is the import directive for URI?

Comment: `import java.net.URI`

Comment: And `FileSystem`?

Comment: `import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem`

Comment: Neat. It would also be nice to have a blurb about how you get the `sparkSession`, but that might be far to involved. It's just always really bloody annoying when you see a good answer but can't tell _which_ libraries are the ones you should use (ex: there's more than one `FileSystem` class in Java)

Comment: @Narfanator I see. I added a line with the session builder to create a simple local session. Please note that in production, your session will be configured differently, and will most likely not choose to have the master node running on the client process.

Comment: Fantastic! It's always frustrating to find the answer you're looking for but not know what setup is required to use it.

Answer (score 3):

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import java.net.URI

var sc = new SparkContext()
if(FileSystem.get(new URI(externalTableLocation), sc.hadoopConfiguration).exists(new Path(externalTableLocation)))
{
  println("File exists")
  val maxPopulatedDate = spark.sql(s"SELECT MAX(DateID) FROM tier_ppw.DistributionDailyFact_Stage")
      log.info("Reading maxPopulatedDate: "+maxPopulatedDate)
}
else
{
   val maxPopulatedDate = "2016-01-01"
   log.info("Reading maxPopulatedDate: "+maxPopulatedDate)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple to do. For example, if you need to check if a directory called `Testfolder` exists or not, use the below code.

```
val s3login = "s3a://Accesskey:Secretkey@Bucket"
val path = "/Myfolder/Testfolder"    
if(FileSystem.get(new java.net.URI(s3login + path), sc.hadoopConfiguration).exists(new Path(s3login + path)))
{
    println("Directory exists")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

S3 is a object based storage,will not support  this kind of syntax. `/*/*`. You also has to set the s3 file system as default and check whether the cluster has access to bucket.

Comment: Can I atleast know whether a particular directory exists? or is there any alternative to this, I can do Try Catch with `spark.read.json(path)` but I don't want to do that thing twice.

Comment: `FileStatus status = fs.getFileStatus(path)`. `FileNotFoundException` => Nothing. `status.isDirectory()` => its there and a directory. Anything else (e.g. `isFile()`, it's there but not a directory)