# pyspark: read.parquet while skip missing files

Tags: pyspark

I think this question related to [Spark : Read file only if the path exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193825/spark-read-file-only-if-the-path-exists/45199045#45199045) but the other one is for Scala.

I am reading files from `hdfs`:

`df_list = sqlContext.read.option('basePath','/data/').parquet(*search_path)`

The problem is if there is a missing file, the `read` command will throw an exception and stop.

Is there a way to let `read.parquet` skip missing files in the list of `search_path`?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same way: Using python hdfs client to test if the directory is an empty one.

Refer to [this link](https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for further usage.