# Avoid "Path does not exist" in dir based spark load

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am loading multiple files from a dir using wildcard as shown below -

```
val df: DataFrame = spark.read
          .format("csv")
          .option("delimiter", ",")
          .schema(schema)
          .load(inputPath + "/*.csv*")
```

This works great for most part. But when the inputPath does not have any csv files in it, I get -

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist
```

Is there a way to avoid this error so that we load if csv files are there but not error if there is nothing to load?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark : Read file only if the path exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193825/spark-read-file-only-if-the-path-exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either put this into `try` block and `catch` the exception

```
try {
       val df: DataFrame = spark.read
          .format("csv")
          .option("delimiter", ",")
          .schema(schema)
          .load(inputPath + "/*.csv*")
    }catch (Exception e) {
    print("Do something else here")
    e.getMessage();
  }
```

or you if you want to check that csv exist, you can first check existence of file

```
import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}
exist = Files.exists(Paths.get(inputPath +  "/*.csv*"))
if (exist){
 val df: DataFrame = spark.read
          .format("csv")
          .option("delimiter", ",")
          .schema(schema)
          .load(inputPath + "/*.csv*")

 }
```

If you have multiple paths in `inputPaths` for instance, you can filter them as

```
inputPaths.filter(f => Files.exists(Paths.get(f +  "/*.csv*")))
```

For hdfs file system, you can replace the above logic with

For single file

```
val conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
val fs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(conf)
val exists = fs.exists(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(inputPath +  "/*.csv*"))
if (exist){
     val df: DataFrame = spark.read
              .format("csv")
              .option("delimiter", ",")
              .schema(schema)
              .load(inputPath + "/*.csv*")
    
     }
```

For multiple files locations stored in array.

```
val conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
val fs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(conf)


inputPaths.filter(f => fs.exists(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(f +  "/*.csv*")))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This won't work with hdfs or object storage paths though.

Comment: I ended up using try catch and consuming that specific error so as not to worry about the file system.