# Check if directory contains json files using org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path in HDFS

Tags: scala, apache-spark, path, hdfs, databricks

I'm following the steps indicated here [Avoid "Path does not exist" in dir based spark load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63602413/avoid-path-does-not-exist-in-dir-based-spark-load) to filter which directories in an array contain json files before sending them to the spark.read method.

When I use

```
inputPaths.filter(f => fs.exists(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(f +  "/*.json*")))
```

It returns empty despite json files existing in the path in one of the paths, one of the comments says this doesn't work with HDFS, is there a way to do make this work?

I running this in a databricks notebook

Answer (score 0):

There is a method for listing files in dir:

```
fs.listStatus(dir)
```

Sort of

```
inputPaths.filter(f => fs.listStatus(f).exists(file => file.getPath.getName.endsWith(".json")))
```