# Spark 2.2.0 - unable to read recursively into directory structure

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

**Problem summary:**
I am unable to read from nested subdirectories using my Spark program, despite setting the required Hadoop configuration (see attempted).
I get the error pasted below.

Any help is appreciated.

**Version:**
Spark 2.2.0

**Input directory layout:**

```
/user/akhanolk/data/myq/parsed/myq-app-logs/to-be-compacted/flat-view-format/batch_id=1502939225073/part-00000-3a44cd00-e895-4a01-9ab9-946064b739d4-c000.parquet
/user/akhanolk/data/myq/parsed/myq-app-logs/to-be-compacted/flat-view-format/batch_id=1502939234036/part-00000-cbd47353-0590-4cc1-b10d-c18886df1c25-c000.parquet
```

...

**Input directory parameter passed:**

/user/akhanolk/data/myq/parsed/myq-app-logs/to-be-compacted/flat-view-format/*/*

**Attempted (1):**

Set parameter in code...

```
val sparkSession: SparkSession =SparkSession.builder().master("yarn").getOrCreate()

//Recursive glob support & loglevel
import sparkSession.implicits._sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.setBoolean("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive", true)
```

Did not see the configuration in place in Spark UI.

**Attempted (2):**

Passed the config from the CLI - spark-submit, and set it in code (see below).

```
spark-submit --conf spark.hadoop.mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive=true \...
```

I do see the configuration in the Spark UI, but same error – cannot traverse into the directory structure..

**Code:**

```
//Spark Session
val sparkSession: SparkSession=SparkSession.builder().master("yarn").getOrCreate()

//Recursive glob support
val conf= new SparkConf()
val cliRecursiveGlobConf=conf.get("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive")
import sparkSession.implicits._
 sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive", cliRecursiveGlobConf)
```

**Error & overall output:**

Full error is at - https://gist.github.com/airawat/77fbdb821410a5a87dfd29ffaf60fdf9

```
17/08/18 15:59:29 INFO state.StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered 
StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /user/akhanolk/data/myq/parsed/myq-app-logs/to-be-compacted/flat-view-format/batch_id=*/* does not exist.
```

Comment: Have you tried this `/user/akhanolk/data/myq/parsed/myq-app-logs/to-be-compacted/flat-view-format/batch_id=*/`?

Comment: @Falan.  Yes - same error.

Comment: then try to check if file actually exists. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405728/apache-spark-check-if-file-exists

Comment: @Falan, have done that basic check and only then posted this question. :)

Comment: Is the directory structure created by Spark itself by writing using a `partitionBy`? If yes, I think you can just try with 

`spark.read.parquet("/user/akhanolk/data/myq/parsed/myq-app-logs/to-be-compacted/‌​flat-view-format/*")`. Let me know if that works.