# HDFS File Existance check in Pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

Can any one suggest the best way to check file existence in pyspark.

currently am using below method to check , please advise.

```
def path_exist(path):

try:
    rdd=sparkSqlCtx.read.format("orc").load(path)
    rdd.take(1)
    return True

except Exception as e:
    return False
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can execute hdfs command from python using `subprocess` :

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['hadoop', 'fs', '-test', '-e', path])
proc.communicate()

if proc.returncode != 0:
    print '%s does not exist' % path
else : 
    print '%s exists' % path
```

see also : [apache spark - check if file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405728/apache-spark-check-if-file-exists)

Answer (score 10):

You can use Java API `org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}` by Py4j.

```
jvm = spark_session._jvm
jsc = spark_session._jsc
fs = jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
if fs.exists(jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("/foo/bar")):
    print("/foo/bar exists")
else:
    print("/foo/bar does not exist")
```

Comment: this is faster than subprocess

Comment: but I haven't been able to use it inside a UDF. is there any way to modify this function to run it using UDF & withColumn?

Comment: Which one is better to use in terms of performance and optimization. This one or subprocess?

Comment: @emeth How would you make this work with a wildcard? (e.g. "/foo/*_bar"). It returns false using Path API...

Answer (score 1):

Following code should work -

```
import subprocess

out=subprocess.check_output("hadoop fs -ls /tmp/file.txt",shell=True)

out=out.strip()

out=out.split("\n")

for l in out:

if l.endswith(".txt"):

print "file exit"
    else:
        print "file not exit"
```

Answer (score 1):

To check files on s3 on pyspark (similar to @emeth's post), you need to provide the URI to the FileSystem constructor.

```
sc = spark.sparkContext
jvm = sc._jvm
conf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
url = "s3://bucket/some/path/_SUCCESS"
uri = jvm.java.net.URI(url)
fs = jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(uri, conf)
fs.exists(jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(url))
```