# Databricks AutoLoader - how to handle spark write transactional (_SUCCESS file) on Azure Data Lake Storage?

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, delta-lake, databricks-autoloader

Databricks spark write method (`df.write.parquet`) for parquet files is transactional. After successfully writing to Azure Data Lake Storage, the file `_SUCCESS` is created in the path where parquet files were loaded.

Example of the folder on ADLS including the `_SUCCESS` file:
[image: image showing the example of the folder on ADLS including the _SUCCESS file]

Is it possible to configure [AutoLoader](https://docs.databricks.com/en/ingestion/auto-loader/index.html#) to load parquet files only in case the write is done with success (`_SUCCESS` file appeared in the folder)? In other words, if listing by AutoLoader folders doesn't include `_SUCCESS` files, parquets files from those folders shouldn't be processed by AutoLoaer.

I was looking for the right option in [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/ingestion/auto-loader/options.html), but it seems like none of the options can help me.

Comment: There is no such conditional loading in auto loader. But you have `modifiedAfter` and `modifiedBefore` where you can able load data before or after  the specified time upon file write successfull. else manually you need to check condition and need to provide those file paths.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @JayashankarGS. AutoLoader feature in Databricks allows you to automatically load data from a path into a Delta table when new files are added to that path. However, there is no built-in option in AutoLoader to conditionally load only parquet files that have a corresponding **_SUCCESS** file in the folder.

If you want to ensure that only parquet files with a successful write **(_SUCCESS file)** are loaded, modify the AutoLoader logic to include a conditional check. If the **_SUCCESS** file is found, load the Parquet files. If the **_SUCCESS** file is not found, indicating a failed write, skip the loading step.

You can try the following:

```
parquet_path = "<Path/to/parq_files>"
success_file_exists = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()).exists(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(parquet_path + "/_SUCCESS"))
```

Reference: [apache spark - check if file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405728/apache-spark-check-if-file-exists)